# Why does an Electron.js app respond slow to user inputs?

Tags: javascript, electron

I ran 'electron-quick-start' app on my PC with Windows 10 via

```
npm start
```

It works, but the app responds to clicks and text typing (e.g. in the Console of DevTool, text inputs) too slow.
What is the problem? Google Chrome and other browsers work fine on my PC.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The problem was hardware acceleration. The members of the Electron devteam told me that hardware acceleration may cause input lag.

```
app.disableHardwareAcceleration();
```

Lag disappeared after writing that command in `main.js`.

Comment: That's kind of an incomplete solution though - there's a reason for hardware acceleration to be enabled in the first place, and disabling it might  lead to other performance losses.

Comment: Maybe, but I was working with the tools I was given back then. Glad I don't have to use Electron anymore, though they might have fixed the issue over years, or at least provided better instructions how to approach this.

Comment: @JohnLaw man, I was pulling my hair out due to a weird issue on Windows. I thought it was a React.js issue but nothing helped. disabling the hardware acceleration solved the problem.